# How to save in Mongoose with await?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

The below code works, but I would like to only use `async/await`, so my question is ´: How can I turn

```
cat.save().then(() => console.log('Saved in db'));
```

into using `await` instead?

The reason I have `mongoose.connection.once()` is to only send commands when MongoDB is connected. if this could use `await` as well, then it would be really great =)

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { connectDb } from './modules/connectDb';
const { Schema } = mongoose;
const catSchema = new Schema({ name: String });
    
(async () => {
  connectDb('testDB');

  mongoose.connection.once('open', () => {
    console.log('MongoDB is connected');

    mongoose.connection.db.listCollections().toArray(function (err, names) {
      console.log(names);
    });

    const catModel = mongoose.model('testColl', catSchema);

    const cat = new catModel({ name: 'Zildjian' });
    cat.save().then(() => console.log('Saved in db'));
  });
})();
```

**connectDb.ts**

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { strict as assert } from 'assert';
import { readToml } from './readToml';

const db = readToml('./config/database.toml');

export function connectDb(
  database: string = db.database,
  uri: string = db.uri,
  username: string = db.username,
  password: string = db.password,
) {
  assert(typeof uri === 'string');
  assert(typeof database === 'string');
  assert(typeof username === 'string');
  assert(typeof password === 'string');

  const URI = `mongodb+srv://${username}:${password}@${uri}/${database}?retryWrites=true&w=majority`;

  try {
    mongoose.connect(URI);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code and make sure the function contains **await** keyword should always **async function** (async keyword should be used before function name). But in your case callback function already defined as async function.

Just change the saving part alone to below, you are good to go.

```
try {
    const catModel = mongoose.model('testColl', catSchema);
    const cat = new catModel({ name: 'Zildjian' });
    const response = await cat.save(); // if error while saving, catch will get executed
    console.log(response); // saved record
    // return success response 
} catch (err) {
    console.log('err' + err);
    // return error response
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make `connectDB` async and then git rid of `mongoose.connection.once()` as you otherwise would need all your Mongoose code to be in there.

```
main().catch((err) => console.log(err));

async function main() {
  await connectDb('testDB');

  const catSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ name: String });
  const catDocument = mongoose.model('testColl', catSchema);

  const catObj = new catDocument({ name: 'Zildjian' });
  await catObj.save();
}
```

**connectDB**

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { strict as assert } from 'assert';
import { readToml } from './readToml';

const db = readToml('./config/database.toml');

export async function connectDb(
  database: string = db.database,
  uri: string = db.uri,
  username: string = db.username,
  password: string = db.password,
) {
  assert(typeof uri === 'string');
  assert(typeof database === 'string');
  assert(typeof username === 'string');
  assert(typeof password === 'string');

  const URI = `mongodb+srv://${username}:${password}@${uri}/${database}?retryWrites=true&w=majority`;

  const options = {
    bufferCommands: false,
    autoCreate: false,
  };

  try {
    await mongoose.connect(URI, options);
  } catch (err: any) {
    throw err.message;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In order to use `await` you have to provide a promise to await for.
`cat.save()` returns a promise, so this should work. Nevertheless you can also only use `await` in async function, so you should also declare the callback function for the open event as async:

```
(async () => {
  connectDb('testDB');

  mongoose.connection.once('open', async () => {
    console.log('MongoDB is connected');

    mongoose.connection.db.listCollections().toArray(function (err, names) {
      console.log(names);
    });

    const catModel = mongoose.model('testColl', catSchema);

    const cat = new catModel({ name: 'Zildjian' });
    await cat.save();
    console.log('Saved in db');
  });
})();
```